# Apply `str.format()` (or str.format_map()`) in multiple steps

Tags: python, string-interpolation

I have a certain template string in Python, e.g.:

```
'{a} and {b}'
```

and two functions, `foo()` and `bar()`. Each of them is providing `a` or `b`. I would like the template string to go first through `foo()` and then through `bar()` so that at the end of `foo()` and `bar()`, I have the full interpolation:

```
def foo(template):
    return template.format(a=10)


def bar(template):
    return template.format(b=20)


print(foo(bar('{a} and {b}')))
# 10 and 20
print(bar(foo('{a} and {b}')))
# 10 and 20
```

Is there an elegant way of doing so?

So far, I have resorted to use this as template:

```
'{a} and {{b}}'
```

which works half way, in that it will not support both `foo(bar())` and `bar(foo())`. Additionally, the template gets harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to hold the format arguments, pass that through `foo()` and `bar()` and then unpack it into the format function.

```
format_dictionary = {
    'a' : 'cats',
    'b' : 'dogs'
}
print('{a} and {b}'.format(**format_dictionary))
```

```
cats and dogs
```